# Next.js, Check if required environment variables are defined on startup

Tags: next.js, environment-variables

When setting up an existing Next.js project, it's easy to forget to create and configure the .env file (or .env.local or similar).
It would be handy if, when starting the server, it would assert that some required variables are undefined, so that you get an error early on instead of a runtime error later when the variable happens to be used in the code.

Something like:

```bash
npm run dev
> next dev
...
Error: the DATABASE_URL environment variable is empty or undefined
```

Is this possible? Or maybe there is some other good practice that makes the problem less relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a file something like checkEnv.js and run it before next dev like here

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "node checkEnv.js && next dev",
  "build": "node checkEnv.js && next build",
  "start": "node checkEnv.js && next start"
}
```

and put some function to validate env variables in checkEnv.js like

```
   require('dotenv').config(); 
    const requiredVariables = ['DATABASE_URL', 'OTHER_REQUIRED_VARIABLE'];
        
        requiredVariables.forEach(variable => {
          if (!process.env[variable]) {
            console.error(`Error: The ${variable} environment variable is empty or undefined`);
            process.exit(1); // Exit with an error code
          } else {
    console.info('All Variables are available');
  }
        });
```

log when all variables are available
[image: log when all variables are available]

log when any .env variable isn't available or empty
[image: log when any .env variable isn't available or empty]

Comment: Have you tested this? The .env variables are not passed to the scripts as far as i can tell, so this will always fail.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet..... but it should work. cause we aren't passing the .env variable to script. the method i provided is just running a normal js file i.e, checkEnv.js before running next dev. and that checkEnv.js file is fetching and verifying data from .env file.

Comment: @foolo I just tested it. and it's working properly . I'll update the answer. it does need you install additional package i.e, 'dotenv'